# Redis - how to check quantity of messages in queue

Tags: php, symfony, redis, queue

I'm using php `Symfony` and every 5 min I would like to send a request that should return quantity of messages waiting in queue.

How can I check quantity of messages in `Redis` queue?

Is it possible to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to interact with Redis?

Answer (score 0):

This is dependend on what Composer package you use to interact with Redis.

In case of `phpredis` you can use the following:

```
$redis->zCount('key');
```

As specified [here](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#zcount) in it's documentation.

If you use `symfony/redis-messenger`, it's unfortunately not supplied by default. However, you could extend the Redis Messenger's transport and run a command yourself like the package does [here](https://github.com/symfony/redis-messenger/blob/4959dca3b135ce92224c415871966b22d164a1e1/Transport/Connection.php#L299).